# YAML_FILE_ERROR: YAML file does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to implement a pipeline on AWS, but I get an error:

```
YAML_FILE_ERROR: YAML file does not exist
```

I don't know why. I'm using github repo for mean stack project, entry file is `docker-compose. Yml`.

Comment: For CodeBuild you need a `buildspec.yml`...

Comment: @jogold yes i know that but i can't understand how to add `buildspec.yml ` where. because `docker-compose.yml` file is for same work

Comment: At the root of your repo.

Comment: @jogold can i rename of my `docker-compose.yml` to `buildspec.yml`? on my github repository.

Comment: No, it's a different type of file, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Comment: @jogold thanks for helping me. after adding `buildspec.yml` getting some error i thing i made mistake on  `buildspec.yml` file cam help to sort out this problem `MEAN STACK` project contains two folder `API`, `FRONT END` and `buildspec.yml`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193085/discussion-between-abhishek-and-jogold).

Comment: @jogold `buildspec.yml` file problem is solved in deploy failed with different different error. i'm to try to figure out but but not help me to short out this problem.

Comment: Please update your question or post another question with your detailed problem and include your `buildspec.yml` file.

Answer (score 29):

AWS CodeBuild expects the `buildspec.yml` file to be at the top level. A common mistake people make is to zip the code folder, which does contain `buildspec.yml`at the top level, but when this zip file is extracted, it creates the code folder and puts the `buildspec.yml` inside that (the way it was locally), meaning `buildspec.yml` is now NOT at the top level.

The solution is: instead of zipping the code folder, go inside the code folder, select all the files, and then do a zip.

This is what Amazon says [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started.html?icmpid=docs_acb_help_panel&shortFooter=true#getting-started-upload-source-code):

> **Important**
>
> Do not include the *(root directory name)* directory, only the
>   directories and files in the *(root directory name)* directory.

It's a quirky little thing that trips many people (including me).

Comment: Or may be the buildspec.yml is on another branch ? :)

Answer (score 5):

Now Amazon has given an option to change the location of the buildspec.yml file or even change the yml file name.

In Developer Tool -> Build -> "Build Project" -> *"Your project Name"* -> "Build details" -> Buildspec -> "Buildspec name - optional"

This is the instruction by AWS for that setting:

> If your buildspec file uses a different name or location, enter its
> path from the source root here (for example, buildspec-two.yml or
> configuration/buildspec.yml).

Answer (score 1):

There is possible you are missing buildspec.yaml or buildspec.yml file, other possibility is that you might wrong name of this file.